# How do I stop object.style.backgroundColor in my js file from removing my class:hover effect in my css file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, background-color

I'm trying to give my users the ability to hover over an option to highlight it, or to press a number key to highlight the corresponding option. The problem is that when the object.style.backgroundColor runs it seems to override my hover effect in my css file. In other words, if I press any key I no longer have a hover effect. What is the solution to this?

```
<!-- my HTML -->
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <p id='option1'>option 1</p>
    <p id='option2'>option 2</p>
    <p id='option3'>option 3</p>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

/* my CSS */
p {
    background-color: red;
}

p:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}


/* my javascript */
// highlights option based on keyup
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    unhighlightOption(); // to unhighlight any already highlighted elements
    switch (event.which) {
        case 49: // 1
        case 97: // numpad 1
            document.getElementById('option1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        break;
        case 50: // 2
        case 98: // numpad 2
            document.getElementById('option2').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        break;
        case 51: // 3
        case 99: // numpad 3
            document.getElementById('option3').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        break;
        default:
            console.log('not a valid key');
    }
});

// loop to unhighlight all options
function unhighlightOption() {
    for (let i=1; i<4; i++) {
        document.getElementById('option' + i).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

I've tried using an addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {code}) to highlight and a addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {code}) to unhighlight, but I'd much rather keep all or most of my styles in my CSS file if at all possible.

Comment: Do everything by setting classes rather than setting inline styles (or do everything with inline styles!) as inline styles take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the specificity of inline styles is more than imported styles.
If you just want to change your CSS code to get this working just add an `important` in the hover block.

```
.hvr:hover {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: This works but also creates another problem for me. I only want the user to highlight one option at a time. If the user is hovering over option 1 and presses 3 on the keypad, now two options are highlighted.

Comment: We should only us js to handle hover style in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the hover effect from css and added "onmouseover="highlight('optionNumber');" to my HTML elements. I added the mouseover function in my javaScript file and now it works the way I want it to. Although I'm admittedly disappointed I couldn't keep my styles in CSS. The resulting code looks like this:

```js
/* my javascript */

// highlights option based on keyup
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  unhighlightOption(); // to unhighlight any already highlighted elements
  switch (event.which) {
    case 49: // 1
    case 97: // numpad 1
      document.getElementById('option1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      break;
    case 50: // 2
    case 98: // numpad 2
      document.getElementById('option2').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      break;
    case 51: // 3
    case 99: // numpad 3
      document.getElementById('option3').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      break;
    default:
      console.log('not a valid key');
  }
});

// loop to unhighlight all options
function unhighlightOption() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById('option' + i).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}

function highlight(optionNumber) {
  unhighlightOption();
  document.getElementById(optionNumber).style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

```css
/* my CSS */

p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- my HTML -->

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p id='option1' onmouseover="highlight('option1');">option 1</p>
  <p id='option2' onmouseover="highlight('option2');">option 2</p>
  <p id='option3' onmouseover="highlight('option3');">option 3</p>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```